# Unwanted automatic placement of labels in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling

I have a polygon layer with attributes `text_x` and `text_y` which I use for label placement with *data defined override*.

In this screeshot the red dots indicate `text_x, text_y` coordinates and as can bee seen, QGIS tries to automatically place labels somewhere inside the polygon in cases where the polygons are not completely inside the map canvas *and* `text_x, text_y` is outside the map canvas too (NO27, NO10, NO11, NO12):

[image]

Little zooming shows the expected correct placement for these lables:

[image]

This behavior is really annoying, therefore my question:

Is there a way to make QGIS placing the labels ***strictly at the given coordinates*** (means ***not rendering*** labels or ***only the part of the label inside the map*** canvas when `text_x, text_y` is outside the map) ***and in no case anywhere else***?

My placement settings that might affect the behaviour are the following:

[image]

Comment: You may try to use the labeling geometry generator to create a point with your text_x and text_y as input, I think it shouldn't put label if the generated point fall outside canvas

Comment: This works even with data defined override activated (obviously geometry generator is mightier than data defined override placement). As a side effect with data defined override kept active moving labels with the mouse still works! Considered this as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the responsible setting (as far as I see at this point) more or less accidentally but not in the *Placement* settings but under *Rendering*:

[image: v]

Unchecking the option *Show all labels for this layer (including colliding labels)* has the desired effect (see NO11 and NO15, even cut at the canvas border!):

[image]

Comment: Just FYI. When exporting the map from the print composer there is an option for the map if you want the cut-off labels included when it's exported or not.